# Why doesn't Perl compile to binary files like python

Tags: perl, compilation, bytecode

It strikes me as a Good Thing (ie. in terms of compilation time), that the Python interpreter will create bytecode .pyc files. I believe python uses some sort of hash to determine if the source has changed and then recompile.

Would this be a good idea for Perl? ( with respect to the larger projects with many dependencies etc ).

Comment: What's with the trademark? Is it something Pythonic?

Comment: @Zaid *Good Thing* is [jargon](http://catb.org/jargon/html/G/Good-Thing.html) and usually emphasized with a trade mark. Geeks. Go figure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For quite long explanation of `.pmc` files, there is [lenghty article on perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=536132), also explaning why nobody uses it.

Comment: Whilst the python functionality is built in it looks like (from what i just read) that perl pmc is a bit of an afterthought!

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there is a way to compile Perl to bytecode, but it has some limitations. See [B::Bytecode](http://p3rl.org/B%3a%3aBytecode).

Answer (score 2):

[Parrot](http://www.parrot.org/) is a bytecode VM which should have been used by next version of Perl, i.e. [Perl6](http://dev.perl.org/perl6/), but apparently no more (thanks to [Barney Schmale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3261294/barneyschmale)'s comment)

Comment: Perl6 is another type of Perl, rather than the "next" as in successor.  It's a language spec, much like common lisp is a language spec.

Comment: Yes, but the only (prototype, incomplete, alpha-stage) implementation of Perl6 seems to be Parrot based.

Comment: Just a note for readers in 2015. This statement is no longer correct. The currently most complete implementation of Perl 6 is Rakudo. Rakudo supports multiple backends. The most comprehensive backend is the Moar VM, followed by the JVM. Parrot support is lagging behind.

Answer (score 0):

It took *longer* for Perl to load from binary than from source.